# Installed Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu but Windows 7 can't boot

Tags: 14.04

After installing Ubuntu I tried to
install Windows 7 from a live USB
and in booting this appeared:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD  

  Status: 0xc0000098  

  Info: The Windows Boot Configuration Data does not contain a valid OS entry.
```

Comment: For your core question: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) But this is likely not an Ubuntu-related problem; you may want to ask for help somewhere Windows is supported, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem shouldn't be having ubuntu installed yet.
However you might run into problems booting your ubuntu if you install windows afterwards.

My suggestion because it sound as if you just installed both systems:
Try again, installing windows first, ubuntu later

You can follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) guide, below the recommended way to do it there is also explained, what to do if you want to keep your ubuntu installation.

Comment: thanks for your reply
ubuntu is installed
while installing win7 from live usb 
this message display
i dont have win7 dvd
i have win7 & ubuntu live usb
how to install win 7

 windows
boot manager Windows failed to
start

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you mean. I hope you finish one installation before you start the other ('while'?).
Have you tried again? And it doesn't work nevertheless?
installing from usb shoudn't be a big difference

Comment: i want to install windows 7.
but it shows windows boot manager error

Comment: this sounds like the problem is your win-install stick; probably the image is broken
Try to recreate the stick